# Is there a way to enforce local package dependencies in npm workspaces when publishing packages?

Tags: npm, eslint, lerna, npm-workspaces

I am trying to use npm workspaces to be able to publish parts of my project as packages:

```
├── packages
│   ├── package-1
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── package-2
│       └── package.json
├── src
│   └── main.ts
├── node_modules
└── package.json
```

I currently do not have any external dependencies declared in the package.json of package-1 although I am using some in the code. However as I have the dependencies in the package.json of my root folder, I can still build my project from the root folder.
This will obviously not work if I am going to publish package-1 as there are dependencies used that only exist in my projects root folder. Is there a trick or tool to prevent using modules that are outside of package-1? Do I need to use lerna for that? Or is there a linter config that is able to check that?

I tried to use `eslint-plugin-workspaces` but that did not show me missing dependencies in my packages.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/reduce-effort-shared-eslint-prettier-configs/).

It explains that you can:

1. Create a new package, e.g. `packages/required-deps` which has a `package.json` file containing `peerDependencies` of the dependencies that you want to enforce.
2. Now in all other packages you only have to remember to add a dependency to your `required-deps` package. This should cause `npm` to complain whenever `npm install` is executed, if some project is missing a peer dependency.

With this in place you can also run `npx install-peerdeps required-deps` or `npx install-peerdeps --dev required-deps` to install the enforced dependencies...